# Adding UI Components in C# WPF in Code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I'm new to C# and WPF format. In my program, I have an array of strings with text, and I want to create a button in the canvas for each string in the array. I've used flex, and in that i can use the addChild command to put something in something else, but I haven't figured out how to do it in WPF yet. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can get you started (untested!):

```
foreach ( var s in textArray )
{
  Button b = new Button();
  //set button width/height/text
  ...
  myCanvas.AddChild( b );

  // position button on canvas (set attached properties)
  Canvas.SetLeft( b, ... ); // fill in the ellipses
  Canvas.SetTop( b, ... );
}
```

A more advanced technique would let you sync the UI to the contents of your array.

I highly recommend the book "WPF Unleashed" to learn WPF.  http://www.adamnathan.net/wpf/

Comment: I ended up using myCanvas.Children.Add(sideBarButtons[i]);

for some reason myCanvas.addChild didn't work at all.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

WPF is streams ahead with the ability to use Binding: you can bind an ItemsControl to your array directly, then tell WPF how to display each item with a Template and it will do it.

```
<!-- ItemsControl is a customisable way of creating a UI element for each item in a
collection.  The ItemsSource property here means that the list of items will be     selected
from the DataContext of the control: you need to set the DataContext of this control, or
the window it is on, or the UserControl it is in, to your array -->

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <!-- The Template property specifies how the whole control's container should look -->
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <!-- The ItemsPanel tells the ItemsControl what kind of panel to put all the items in; could be a StackPanel, as here; could also be a Canvas, Grid, WrapPanel, ... -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- The ItemTemplate property tells the ItemsControl what to output for each item in the collection.  In this case, a Button -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!-- See here the Button is bound with a default Binding (no path): that means the Content be made equal to the item in the collection - the string - itself -->
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Width="200" Height="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Hope that helps!

Reference:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx

Comment: myCanvas.Children.Add(sideBarButtons[i]); is what I ended up using, and it worked like I wanted.