# How to set the amount of fields defined by user in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

How do I set a number in a up/down box then press a button to show me a second form with the amount of fields (like labels with text boxes) defined in the up/down box? I'm new to programming so try to explain in really simple terms if you can. Thanks

Comment: Read the value in the up/down box (parse it to an integer). Then you'll have to create the controls dynamically (with a loop).

Answer (score 0):

1. Code based solution you can implement now

   Container controls in VB.Net inherit usually inherit from [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) control which owns a collection by name Children.

   You can add dynamically created controls to this collection to create the second form.
2. Complex but technically sound solution

   Invest sometime to learn XAML and create XAML templates to this job for you. Refer the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274507/adding-ui-components-in-c-sharp-wpf-in-code-behind) which solves same problem in C#.